# Save my Unique ID (String) and retrieving it later when I re-launch my Java application

Tags: java, save

I want to save a Unique ID (which is a String) which gets created when I launch my Java application. Now I want to save this somewhere (I think in some file on the disk) so that when I relaunch my application I should be able to read it and use that ID.

I want to know what is the good way to saving such ID. I am thinking of creating a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file and save it then retrieve it from it when I relaunch application. Is there a better or standard way for this?

**EDIT :**

Additionally what should be the folder location for storing on the disk. Should it be relative to my execution path or some Logged-in user specific path?

Comment: yeah that is good option, But also depends on what you are storing in it

Comment: The file is ok, just be careful of storing it in the appropiate folder for the OS (Users/yourUser/AppData in windows, /home/yourUser in linux) etc.

Comment: Another option is preference api. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** If its the **same Java application that writes or reads this String**, then use `Serialization`, it will be in non-readable form when saved.

**2.** If **reading and writing is from different program**, then use `Text file`.

**3.** Using `Property file` will be also a good approach.

Comment: I'd go with a simple serialization as well.

Comment: @KumarVivek : Thanks for your answer. Ideally what should be the folder location if I use Property file?[see my updates in question].

Comment: I usually drop my Property file directly in my bin folder, that helps my program to find it easily........

Answer (score 3):

If your app/program needs to store more data at some point sqlite3 might be the best option for you. It is easy to implement and use.

[Download sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

EDIT: How many IDs will be stored in the app? If there are just a few, a textfile or property file is enough.

EDIT2: Navigate to your Documents folder on your machine and you will see folders of programs/games. Thats where you should place the file/db. However you can also store it in the installation path on your hard drive. Also make sure your user launches the app trough a shortcut, not the actual execution file

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileWriter and File classes from Java.

It should be something like that:

```
File f = new File(your path here);
if (f.exists()){
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(your path here));
String a = br.readLine();
br.close();
}else{
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(your path here);
fw.write(your ID String);
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

I hope this is want u meant.
Best regards

edit: just noticed too late that your edited your post....